# Radio button position HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

For my first website, I had to create a simple HTML/CSS form. But my problem was in the fact that my radio buttons don't want to hear what I order him.

[image: Without float]

(this is without float)

I want it below the email input together, but the more I give `margin-left`, the more apart (in width) those two radio buttons get.

[image: Code below]

(this is the code below)

How to fix the radio button position problem?

As you can see I have tried `last-child` but it doesn't show any effect. In my code for the footer there is no auto height or width.

I am not allowed to use JavaScript. Only pure HTML and CSS.

**HTML**

```
<form> 
<label class="field">Name:</label><input id="email" type="Name" placeholder="Name"><br>
<label class="field">Lastname:</label> <input id="lastname" type="lastname" placeholder="Lastname"><br>
<label class="field">Email:</label> <input id="Email" type="Email" placeholder="Email"><br>             
<label class="radio">No<input  type="radio" name="st" value="No"/></label><br>
<label class="radio">Yes<input  type="radio" name="st" value="Yes"  /></label><br>              
<label class="textarea"><textarea></textarea></label><br>
<label class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></label><br>
<label class="feedback">Feedback:</label>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
  /*FORM*/
    form { 
        width: 100%;
        margin-top:5px;
    }

    label.field {
        text-align: right;
        width:100px;
        float:left;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding-top:4px;
    }

    label.radio{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    border:1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;        
}


    label.radio:last-child{

        margin-right: 10px;

    }

    label.feedback{
        text-align:right;
        width:100px;
        float:left;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding-top:4px;
        margin-top: -40px;
    }
```

Comment: Hi ! Please note those are called "radio buttons", not "ratios". I had a hard time understanding where the ratios you were talking about were :-) I edited your post accordingly. [Here's an explanation](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2006-04-08/open-space/27786093_1_button-station-radio) about why it's called "radio button". As a side note, you would need to use the `for` attribute on those labels, so that clicking on the label gives focus to the related field (or checks it if we're talking about a radio button or a checkbox)

Comment: I am deeply sorry, I just noticed that myself to.

Comment: I don't understand well what you want... Il you want a element go to the line after a float, you must insert a clear:both element

Comment: But they wont be inline, if you clear that..

Comment: No reason to be sorry, just to mention :-) And you've no reason to be ashamed of your English neither ! In addition, I would strongly suggest that you check about the the different values for `display`in CSS properties, as well as the concept of HTML flow. Those are 2 very basic things you would need to understand if you want to understand the rest better.

Comment: I understand, that was my first idea to use `display:inline` but it did not shaked anything

Comment: The `clear:both` fixed the align thing. But I had to brake up the radios to radio1 and radio2 and by forse moved radio2. radio1 css i let same, but radio2 i moved `margin-top: -35px` and `margin-left: 145px`. I wish there was an easier way for this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a list, and clear on the LI. Get rid of the breaks. You should reset the list first: `ul, li {margin:0;padding:0list-style:none}`

```
li { clear:both }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <label class="field">Name:</label>
       <input id="email" type="Name" placeholder="Name">
    </li>
    <li>
       <label class="field">Lastname:</label>
       <input id="lastname" type="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
    </li>
    ....
 </ul>
```

Lists are semantic, which makes then good for people with disabilities. You can also use the list for formatting the layout by adjusting margin/padding.

See: [A List Apart - Prettier Accessible Forms](http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms)

Comment: In this, I actually used list when I made the first demo of the forms. But it radio problem still was there.